# Which regression analysis to choose?

Tags: regression, categorical-data

I would like to estimate an effect of two nominal independent variables and 3 ordinal variables on one nominal variable. Which regression would best fit this purpose?

Comment: It will be better if you indicate nature  problem along with hypotheses you are working on ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The response variable is a nominal variable, therefore it is a classification problem. If it has two possible values, logistic regression can be used. If it has more than two possible values, multi-class logistic regression can be used.

Comment: What I'd like to do is basically to see an association between 1 nominal variable controlling for 1 nominal + 3 ordinal variables and one nominal (with more than two categories).

Comment: @Dimi https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_logistic_regression

Comment: I do not think that we can do multinomial logistic regression combining ordinal and nominal variables.